# Rails application w/multiple AWS Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

We have an application that needs to access different secure S3 buckets based on the logged in user. Is it possible to have multiple AWS AKID/SAK's associated with a Rails application, and switch them within the application based on user context. We are currently running Rails 5.x.

Comment: There are a few ways you could accomplish this. Without knowing anything about your app, scopes, or anything like that, I’d recommend [AWS Security Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html). We use STS to limit access to buckets and paths in buckets, based on the logged in user, in a Django app, and it works perfectly. Could be implemented in a Rails app, too.

Answer (score 0):

we ended up using

```
require 'aws-sdk'
Aws.config.update(
  region: 'us-west-2',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('akid', 'secret')
)
```

from the AWS SDK. The way we are doing it, is every time we upload an asset or create a presigned URL we are calling it with the credentials stored in the database.